# I keep getting zeros from a method

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

This is the main method

```
package javaapplication50;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication50 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.print(" > Enter student ID: ");

                int id = in.nextInt();

                System.out.print("> Enter student First Name: ");

                String name = in.next();

                System.out.print("> Enter student Last Name: ");
                String last = in.next();

                JavaApplication50 app = new JavaApplication50();

                System.out.println(" > Enter students Grades: ");

                double aptTestGrade = app.readStudentGrade(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of Aptitude Test: ", in);
                double introYearGrade = app.readStudentGrade(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of Introductory Year: ", in);
                double schoolGrade = app.readStudentGrade(0, 100, " > Enter the grade of School: ", in);

                System.out.println("");

                String AF;

                double finalgrade = 0;

                calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);

                if (finalgrade >= 90 && finalgrade <= 100) {

                    AF = "Medicine";

                } else if (finalgrade >= 85 && finalgrade <= 90) {

                    AF = "Engineering";
                } else if (finalgrade >= 80 && finalgrade <= 85) {
                    AF = "Computing";

                } else if (finalgrade >= 75 && finalgrade <= 80) {
                    AF = "Science";

                } else if (finalgrade >= 70 && finalgrade <= 75) {

                    AF = "Economics";

                } else {

                    AF = "Not Assigned";

                }

                System.out.println("> " + name + " " + last + " (ID #" + id + ") has been added to the system.");

                System.out.println("> Final Grade:  " + finalgrade + "  Assigned Faculty:  " + AF);
```

I used this method to enforce the user to enter test grade between 0 and 100.

```
    double readStudentGrade(double min, double max, String message, Scanner in) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(message);
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            if (input <= max && input >= min) {
                return input;
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(" >    Invalid input! ((must be between " + min + " and " + max + ")");
                System.out.println(" >    Please try again.\n"
                        + "");
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }

    }
```

this method is to calculate the final grade but for some reason I keep getting zero as grade .

```
public static double calculateFinalGrades(double aptTestGrade, double introYearGrade, double schoolGrade) {

    double finalgrade;

    double finalgrade1 = (aptTestGrade * 30) / 100;

    double finalgrade2 = (introYearGrade * 50) / 100;

    double finalgrade3 = (schoolGrade * 20) / 100;

    finalgrade = finalgrade1 + finalgrade2 + finalgrade3;

    return finalgrade;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No problem. Please select one of our answers as correct. So people know the answers are credible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here.

```
double finalgrade = 0; // finalgrade = 0

calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade); // method returns finalgrade but return value never assigned to finalgrade
```

To fix this:

```
finalgrade = calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);
```

So now when the method returns it assigns the return value to finalgrade and updates its value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the `finalgrade` variable:

```
double finalgrade = calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);
```

Answer (score 1):

`finalgrade` is assigned to 0, instead it needs to hold `calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);` and then you are invoking `calculateFinalGrades` but nothing hold the returned value so

add this:

```
finalgrade = calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);
```

instead of this:

```
double finalgrade = 0;
calculateFinalGrades(aptTestGrade, introYearGrade, schoolGrade);
```